# accessing variables from another class

Tags: c#

i have 2 classes(a form class and a user-control class) and in the form one i have a list. I would like to access that list from the user control class. How can i do it ? i could pass a reference from the form class to the user control class , but i am curious if there is another way ?

Regards,
Alexandru Badescu

Comment: is the problem that list is private?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing it as a reference is your best option - this is how you should do it.

It keeps coupling between the user control and the form to a minimum and allows the user control to be used elsewhere.

Comment: do you have any other solutions?

Comment: @SaeedAlg - You are assuming immutability. @Badescu Alexandru - The list can be passed as an `IEnumerable` or converted to a `ReadOnlyCollection` before being passed.